# FBConnect and personal upload email address

Tags: iphone, upload, facebook

I am writing an iPhone app that needs to be able to upload photos to Facebook as a side effect of sending them in an email. It seems like a gigantic pain to create the album and upload the photos; is there any way that I can get the user's personal upload email through the API and just add that to the recipients in the email that is sent?

Comment: Sounds like a huge privacy issue. A user can deny you access to the API, but it cannot deny you access to the e-mail once you have it. (Although I've never used FBConnect), with that said, I doubt it's possible to get the e-mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'm sorry, but that's not possible. Check out the FQL tables reference:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User_%28FQL%29